# Change datetime axis in pandas?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, matplotlib

I have made a plot with the following datetime axis.

[image]

How can I change it such that is begins at 6AM and ends at 3AM (instead of beginning at 7pm and ending at 4pm)? If it's relevant, this is how I am making the plot:

```
df.plot(df.sttm, legend=False)
```

where df is pandas dataframe.

Comment: But, in the plot the ticks end at 4 pm and not 6 am?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo on  my part. I will fix the post.

Comment: Shouldn't it end at 3am instead of 5am according to the frequency interval of 3hours?

Comment: Yes, OP has been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`tshift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#shifting-lagging) method that changes all the dates in the index by a specified number of offsets.(Assumes that the index is a datetime object).

***Demo:***

```
from datetime import datetime
index = pd.date_range(start=datetime(2016,10,6,19), end=datetime(2016,10,7,16), freq='3H')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10, (8,1)), index=index)
df.index
```

gives:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2016-10-06 19:00:00', '2016-10-06 22:00:00',
               '2016-10-07 01:00:00', '2016-10-07 04:00:00',
               '2016-10-07 07:00:00', '2016-10-07 10:00:00',
               '2016-10-07 13:00:00', '2016-10-07 16:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='3H')
```

Selecting an offfset to create the lag.

```
df.tshift(-13, freq='H').index
```

gives:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2016-10-06 06:00:00', '2016-10-06 09:00:00',
               '2016-10-06 12:00:00', '2016-10-06 15:00:00',
               '2016-10-06 18:00:00', '2016-10-06 21:00:00',
               '2016-10-07 00:00:00', '2016-10-07 03:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='3H')
```

This keeps the column values as it is and does not produce any shift in them. It simply alters(shifts) the index axis.

Comment: I need the column values to be shifted as well. Is there a way to accomplish that?

Comment: How do you want the column values to appear? AFAIK, your index starts from `19:00:00` which gets shifted to `6:00:00`. What values do the column take as it does not have any value at present corresponding to `6:00:00`. It must remain the same, right? If you shift them by that many positions, you would only get NaN's which is not what you want after all.